# Find polynomial with specific constraints

Tags: functions, polynomials

Say I am given a degree $d$, an upper and a lower limit $L_{min}$ and $L_{max}$ and a constant $k$ with $L_ {min} \leq k \leq L_ {max}$. How can I find a polynomial in the form of 
$f(x)=k + a_1x^1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \ldots + a_dx^d$ for which the following properties hold:

1. The polynomial degree must be $2 \leq d \leq 8$.
2. For every $a_i$  there holds $L_{min} <= a_i \leq= L_{max}$
3. For every $L_{min} \leq x \leq L_{max}$ every $L_{min} \leq f(x) \leq L_{max}$

Comment: Maybe constraint (3) should read:  $L_{min} \leq f(x) \leq L_{max}$ For every $x$ such that $L_{min} \leq x \leq L_{max}$

Comment: It looks like any increasing polynomial with non-zero positive coefficients would satisfy your 3rd requirement, given that the first 2 are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Such a polynomial might not exist. For example, suppose $L_{min}=0$ and $L_{max}=1$ and $k=0$. Then for every polynomial $f(x)=k+a_1x+\ldots +a_dx^d$, one has $f(1)=k+a_1+\ldots+a_d \geq k+a_d \geq 2$, which contradicts condition (3).

Comment: I guess this is only on case where the polynomial does not exist, and it does not prove that that it can't exist in general. for example, a second degree equation that has a1, a2, a3 all non zero and >0, between 1 and 10 satisfies the constraints.